# In C# can you set constraints on events?

Tags: c#, events, constraints

I want to limit the types that can subscribe to a particular event based on the interface they implement.

I.e. I want an object "Employee" implementing IPerson to subscribe to an event handler but another object "Truck" implementing a totally different interface to be restricted.  Out of the box any object implementing the correct method pattern can subscribe.

How do I limit this?

The reason I ask is I am implementing the Observer pattern but trying to do so with C# Events.  I have an example working similar to [what MSDN has here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx).

My concern though still is ANY object with ANY structure (so long as it contains the proper delegate method) can be executed when the event fires.  So in my example above an Employee could implement the method that makes sense for the objects in my example, but then anyone could go make another class - "truck" in my example above, with any structure (so long as it again implements the method) and tie into the subjects event...  This is definitely more of a concern over object usage and good design and maybe I am being nit picky here but this is bothering me.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use the observer pattern, not events.

Comment: There are some interesting answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078175/can-an-event-listener-be-limited-to-only-having-one-subscriber) that may be of help

Comment: What's the purpose of this? Out of curiosity?

Comment: Matt this is exactly what I am doing, but want to implement the pattern WITH C# events as the holder rather than a list of the types and iterating through and calling the method to notify.  Are you suggesting C# Events is not a good thing to incorporate into this pattern?

Comment: @dbobrowski : sorry but I can't find any relations between observer pattern and what you've asked in the question, could you please elaborate bit more?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In C# can you set constraints on events?

Nope.

> I want to limit the types that can subscribe to a particular event based on the interface they implement.

Event listeners are *instances of delegates of a type compatible with the event type*. "Types" are not listeners of events.

> I.e. I want an object "Employee" implementing IPerson to subscribe to an event handler but another object "Truck" implementing a totally different interface to be restricted.

An "employee" object doesn't listen to an event in the first place. The only thing that listens to an event is a *delegate object*.

Are you saying that you only want to accept delegates that are delegates to methods that happen to be instance methods of a particular class?  That is a very strange thing to do and **I recommend that you not attempt to do so**.

It is not possible to prevent that *at compile time*, but if you are really hell-bent on doing this strange thing, you can do it at runtime.

To do so, as the other answers note, you can create adder and remover accessor methods for the event, and then put a check in the adder that verifies that the receiver of the delegate is of a type you approve of, and throw an exception if it is not.

But again, this sounds like an extraordinarily bad idea. It is up to the listener to decide whether or not they are interested in the event, not up to the event source to vet its listeners. Users have the reasonable expectation that any accessible event can be listened to by any delegate of a compatible type.

Perhaps you can explain why you want to do this strange thing; there might be a better way to achieve your aim.

Comment: hmm...  so in reading your response it seems like you feel this is a bad idea and it is strange.  Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @dbobrowski: Yes. Why do you want to do this? The editor publishing the newspaper can choose to *publish* an edition or *not publish* it, but does not typically decide *who cannot subscribe*. The subscriber doesn't control the publishing schedule, but can decide whether or not to subscribe. That's the relationship people expect publishers and subscribers to have; changing that relationship is a surprising and unusual thing to do, so I'd imagine you'd have a pretty compelling reason to do so.

Comment: @dbobrowski every system including the .NET and C# language is designed to support common scenarios that should solve most of the problems you may encounter. If you try and do something the system is not designed for it may indicate the flaw of the system, but it's much  more likely that you are trying to do something strange and not recommended.

Comment: Right I understand why you say this is odd - see my edit in original question.  Maybe I am overthinking this, maybe this is a non issue...but my concern is around allowing any object to be an observer of the subject when maybe it makes no logical sense for that object to be a subscriber.

Comment: I suppose this could be accomplished without much work in the traditional observer pattern as well by implementing the IObserver interface, but I suppose you could lock this down by constraining the collection...  Again - maybe I am over thinking...  should ANY object be able to become an observer?

Comment: Just because you can't imagine why someone else should subscribe, doesn't mean you need to restrict it. "A successful tool is one that was used to do something undreamt of by its author." -- Stephen C. Johnson

Comment: @JoeWhite I like this - I am convinced.  Eric, your example helped me clarify as well.  It seems like I was re-purposing the pattern in an incorrect fashion.

Comment: "But again, this sounds like an extraordinarily bad idea. It is up to the listener to decide whether or not they are interested in the event, not up to the event source to vet its listeners."
--It's called democracy, I believe...

Comment: @DejanStanič: As Tom Stoppard said, "It's not the *voting* that's democracy, it's the *counting*."

Answer (score 8):

This is a really bad idea. Please don't do this.

What are you trying to protect against really? Any 'hostile' type can implement the interface (and if they can't see the interface because it's internal to your project, then there's no reason to not make the event internal too), so your blacklist isn't all that well enforced. What's worse, this makes things harder for types on the whitelist - they won't be able delegate listeners to instances of 'close', related types easily. Even the use of a closure (through a lambda / anonymous method)  might suddenly break subscriptions - the 'presenting' subscription object might become an instance of a (blacklisted) compiler-generated class.

This is a poor security mechanism and it offers no compile-time safety. It doesn't do a good job of keeping the bad guys out, and makes life difficult for the good guys.

Anyway, this is possible - you will need to use a custom implementation for the event and validate every subscription request.

```
//Please don't do this.

private EventHandler myEventField = delegate { };

// Add synchronization if required.
public event EventHandler MyEvent
{
   add
   {
      if(value.Target is IPerson)
        myEventField += value;

      else throw new ArgumentException("Subscriber must implement IPerson", "value");
   }

   remove { myEventField -= value; }
}


private void RaiseMyEvent() { myEventField(this, EventArgs.Empty); }
```

Comment: See my response to Matt above - are events not appropriate for Observer?  I do not wish to allow just anyone to subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine why you need this, looks bit messy for me at first glance, but anyway you can encapsulate this restriction logic in event holder itself and expose `Subscribe(delegate handler)` to subscribe to event rather than exposing public event itself

```
class EventHolder
{
  private event EventHandler<NewUpdateEventArgs> NewUpdate;

  public void SubscribeForNewUpdates(object subscriptionOwner, 
                                     Action<NewUpdateEventArgs> callback) 
  {
     if (subscriptionOwner.GetType() == ... or subscriptionOwner is ...)
     {
        this.NewUpdate += .. subscribe callback
     }
  }
 }
```

Comment: @Saintedlama : you are right. But all this is nothing more than details of a particular implementation, I've provided an idea