# Old ViewModels catch events

Tags: c#, winforms, events, mvvm

I am making a Winforms program, using and MVVM-like pattern. All my data is connected to a `SessionModel` which is passed to all  `ViewModels` (I know this probably isn't the best way to do things, but thats what I got).

My issue is this: Inside a `ViewModel` I have an event listener, which connects an event to a method, like this:

```
// Base constructor
public MyViewModel(SessionModel session) 
{
    this.session = session;
    MyUserControl.MyEvent_OnActivate += AddItem;
}

// This method should be called, whenever the event is invoked
private void AddItem() 
{
    session.Items.AddItem();
}
```

A new instance of the ViewModel is generated each time the corresponding `View` is shown. And here arises my problem. Because everything is fine **the first time** I load the `View` and `ViewModel`. But **the second time** I visit it, the first instance still exists (although not referenced anywhere) and thereby picks up the event as well. The result is that the method `AddItem()` is called **twice** (once from each instance of the `ViewModel`. If I navigate to the `View` once again, it would be called three time, and so on.

My `View`and `ViewModel` is loaded from the `MainForm` like this:

```
// When called, this method loads the view and view model
private void ShowMyView() 
{
    MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel(session);
    MyView view = new MyView(viewModel);
    ShowContent(view);
}

// Clears content panel and shows new view
private void ShowContent(UserControl view)
{
    while (pnlContent.Controls.Count > 0)
    {
        pnlContent.Controls[0].Dispose();
    }
     pnlContent.Controls.Add(view);
}
```

Is there some clever way of clearing old instances of view models, since the garbage collection apparently isn't fast enough?

Answer (score 0):

> although not referenced anywhere...

Event subscriptions do keep the subscribers to be referenced. The old viewmodel should unsubscribe from `MyUserControl.MyEvent_OnActivate` whenever a new one is initialized. Make your ViewModel disposable and perform the cleanup in the `Dispose` method.

Comment: So basically, whenever I change view (and thereby view model), I should dispone any existing view models?

Comment: Not necessarily by `Dispose` (in WPF world the dispose pattern is not really used for example), but yes. It can be a `Detach`, `Close` or anything but you must unsubscribe from the events, because they keep the references alive. Even if it does not cause such obvious problems, the event handlers are often the causes of memory leaks.

Comment: But how do I "catch" the obsolete instance of the `ViewModel`? I basically forget everything about the, the moment I go to a different `View`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, by getting rid of the `event` and simply listening directly to the `delegate`, as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078175/can-an-event-listener-be-limited-to-only-having-one-subscriber).

The code then looks like this:

```
public class MyUserControl
{
    internal delegate void MyDelegate();
    (...)
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyVieWModel(SessionModel session)
    {
        this.session = session;
        MyUserControl.MyDelegate = AddItem;
    }

    public void AddItem()
    {
        (...)
    }
}
```

Comment: An event is a wrapped delegate so this is unlikely to solve the problem fully. Just make sure that you remove all handlers when the instance is no longer needed.

Comment: It is a solution which has its limitations indeed. From what I understand, this removes the subscription option, in which an even can have multiple active listeners (a delegate can't?). In other words, this might not be a viable solution for everyone, but it was in my case. I will update my post with some more details, once I get a better hang of it.

Comment: A delegate that returns void can have multiple subscriptions (multicast delegate)

Comment: Besides, the code does contain a violation of MVVM: the ViewModel 'knows' the View. In MVVM the View binds to the ViewModel (databinding)

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd thanks for the clarification. I know that I am slaughtering MVVM a bit, using it the way I am. It was a work around, since my views contained user controls, which I had to get to "talk to" the view model, which they did not know.

Comment: Use databinding in xaml, there is no need for the user controls to know the view models

Comment: I would love to, but WinForms was decided for this project (not my decission). But a recommendation for others, would be that MVVM + WinForms is doable, but far from optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem that `MyControl` still keeping references to the previous viewmodels.

Winforms perfectly suitable for MVVM pattern. It supports `data-binding` (not so powerful as in WPF)

> I know that I am slaughtering MVVM a bit, using it the way I am. It
>   was a work around, since my views contained user controls, which I had
>   to get to "talk to" the view model, which they did not know

By referencing view control in the viewmodel you break MVVM pattern. If you continue to "follow" MVVM - you are on your own, different kind of problems start gathering and after few weeks you decide that MVVM pattern not doable ;)

Simple suggestion for your particular case, without knowing much about application context, user control should now about viewmodels it affect on.

You can bind collection of viewmodels to the user control where it simple calls it's methods

```
private UserControl_OnActivate()
{
    foreach (var viewmodel in ViewModels)
    {
        viewmodel.AddItem()
    }
}
```

Now user control know about viewmodel and viewmodel know nothing about user control(view) - MVVM pattern.
Old viewmodel's references will be garbage collected when you update `ViewModels` collection with new ones.